# Convert this recurrence relation to its closed-form

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I struggle with the following relation that I need (hope) to convert to a closed-form. I write in detail only the point at which I am stuck, as I can take it from there to finish the task. The relation concerns the function $p_{a,b}$, which is a probability, and more specifically we have the following relationships

$$p_{n+a,r}=\left[\prod_{λ=0}^{r-1}γ_1(λ)\right]p_{n+a-r,0},\quad 0\leq r\leq a \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$p_{n+a,0}=\sum_{κ=0}^{a-1}γ_2(κ)p_{n+a-1,κ} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

From the above I can deduce:

$$p_{n+a,0}=\sum_{κ=0}^{a-1}\left[γ_2(κ)\left[\prod_{λ=0}^{κ-1}γ_1(λ)\right]p_{n+a-κ-1,0}\right] \tag{3}\label{3}$$

The functions $γ_1(\cdot)$ and $γ_2(\cdot)$ are also some (arbitrary) probabilities.

I would like to derive **an expression of $p_{n+a,0}$ w.r.t $p_{n,0}$** for all $a\geq 0$. If I do this, then I can derive the closed-form of $p$.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I understand your sentence about the basins. However, I think the way you manipulated the index λ is incorrect. This is because λ is the index of the product operator. I cannot use it outside of the product and then plug it in and pretend they are the same integer. Sorry if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Forget the comparison with basins. Better say that between $(n+a,r)$ and $(n+a-r,0)$, you could imagine diagonal intermediate steps $$(n+a,r) \to (n+a-1,r-1) \to (n+a-2,r-2) \to  \cdots (n+a-\lambda,r-(\lambda)) \to (n+a-(\lambda+1),r-(\lambda+1))  \to \cdots \to (n+a-r,0)$$, each step being governed by multiplication by $\gamma_1(\lambda)$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. More correctly, each step $t=0,1,\dots$ is a multiplication of $γ_1(t)$. How can I proceed further with this?

Comment: I mean that it is simpler to say it (and use it) in this way than by grouping at once as a product.

Comment: Besides, knowing the (probabilistic) origin of the issue might shed some light...